# unable to understand callback in javascript. please check

Tags: javascript, callback

I have written my code to test the callback . but i am getting answer 5 directly for the two calls. I need 2 and 5 respectively. How to achieve it.

var count = 0;

```
function increment(number, callback) {
    count = count + number;
    setTimeout(callback, 10000);

}

var done = function() {
    console.log(`count is :${count}`);
};
increment(2, done);
increment(3, done);
```

Comment: you can pass `count` value to `done`

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the number to `count` **immediately**, then scheduling a callback to show the result. That means as soon as the two calls to `increment` run, `count` is `5`. Then 20 and 50 seconds later, that is shown. You can see that if we do `console.log(`count after calls :${count}`);` after the two calls (I've lowered the timeouts to 2 and 5 seconds):

```js
var count = 0;

function increment(number, callback) {
  count = count + number;
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);

}

var done = function() {
  console.log(`count is :${count}`);
};
increment(2, done);
increment(3, done);
console.log(`count after calls :${count}`);
```

Instead, you'll want to add `number` to `count` in the timer callback (I've lowered the timeouts to 2 and 5 seconds):

```js
var count = 0;

function increment(number, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Our timer callback fired, update count
    count += number;
    // Call the main callback
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

var done = function() {
  console.log(`count is :${count}`);
};
increment(2, done);
increment(3, done);
```